# Windows netsh WinForm Process.Start unable to take arguments

Tags: winforms, arguments, trace, process.start, netsh

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 C#.  I'm trying to create a simple Winform application for our remote small site employees that will help them assist IT remote support diagnose latency issues between their client computer and some enterprise application (exchange servers, webapps, databases, etc. on the network) from a netsh trace capture file.

IT remote small site support is expected to open the trace file and isolate the cause of packet latency between the two end points.

The goal here is for remote small site employees to launch a Winform App, click a button that launches netsh, capture a trace to a file, and to close netsh after a period of minutes.  I haven't written the code for the timer yet.  The initial code below is supposed to launch netsh which it does without arguments.  It displays a window and the netsh> prompt appears.  When I try to run netsh with arguments the Winform netsh command window flashes and then immediately closes. I've searched numerous articles and tried many of the suggested code segments but none seem to work.  Any help would be appreciated.

****************** Code**********************

```
    private void DegradationCaptureStartButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            startInfo.FileName = "netsh.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = "trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=c://temp//billstrace.etl";
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Your code will start a trace session, opening a file in specified directory. The console window is closed immediately because the process has exited. This is not a console application, and also happens if you input the same command in a Cmd.exe window, except the Cmd console window does not closed, because it belongs to another process. If you want to see the netsh report about the started session, capture the stdout and pass it to a TextBox control. Unless you forgot to issue a `netsh trace stop`, then the prompt would be an "Access Denied" => the file/session already exists...

Comment: ... When you close the tracing session (`netsh trace stop`), the console window will be visible a bit longer, because it takes time to build the .cab file. Then you'll also see whether the previous command was successfull or not.

Comment: Thanks Jimi.  I appreciate the explanation.  To stop the trace, would I need to know which process ID of the running trace to stop it.  If I launch a netsh trace stop the system will display an error - no trace started?

Comment: `netsh` traces are not related to a specific ProcessId. You can start the trace from you application, then stop it from a console cmd session (`netsh -> trace -> show status` / `netsh -> trace -> stop`). As a suggestion, I'ld modify the arguments string this way: `@"trace start persistent=yes capture=yes tracefile=c:\temp\billstrace.etl"`.